# String.gsub() to extract last word in string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string where the words within are separated by periods, what would be the best way for returning the last word?
My guess would be to use `string.gsub`, but i'm having a hard time figuring out the correct syntax

here's an example:

```
str = "These.Are.A.Few.Words.But.I_only_want_this"
```

Desired output would be:

```
I_only_want_this
```

Note that i don't need to treat any magical characters as such, they can stay in the string no problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```lua
str:gsub('.*%.', '')
```

`.*` - Match zero or more (`*`) of *any* character (`.`), taking the longest sequence possible.
`%.` - Match a literal `.` character.

Example:

```
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> str = "These.Are.A.Few.Words.But.I_only_want_this"
> str:gsub('.*%.', '')
I_only_want_this    1
```

Comment: Did something similar earlier on, but i missed the last arg, thank you very much, worked like a charm

Comment: Why use `gsub` rather than `str:match".*%.(.*)"`?

Comment: @Luatic Primarily because the question itself was focused on `gsub`. Note that there is a difference between `str:match".*%.(.*)"` and `str:gsub('.*%.', '')` in how they handle a missing prefix: `string.gsub('No_prefix', '.*%.', '')` -> `'No_prefix'`,  `string.match('No_prefix', '.*%.(.*)')` -> `nil`.

Comment: Indeed. My solution would have to be adapted to `str:match".*%.(.*)" or str` to deal with that properly.